# designing for Kindle Fire in Photoshop

Tags: android, mobile, resolution, dpi, kindle-fire

I've reviewed all of the android design documentation, but I am still a little confused on how I should setup my photoshop file if I am making an app for just the Kindle Fire.

It's 1024x600 with 160 dpi. Should my new photoshop fle mirror the resolution and dpi of the device?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exact pixel resolution (1024x600) is all you need to worry about; the DPI of your Photoshop file won't affect your output at all. That only affects your physical output size if you're measuring it in a dimension such as inches, mm, etc. (Like if you're printing it out, a 1024 x 600 pixel image set to 160 DPI would print by default at 6.4" -- 1024/160 -- by 3.75" -- 600/160).

Comment: thank you! I thought so, but had to be sure :)

Comment: You're welcome. :) Never hurts to double check!